# Magento 2: "The requested qty is not available" message autohides quickly

Tags: magento2

How do I prevent "The requested qty is not available" message from autohiding in product page while adding products to cart. I want to let user close the message instead of auto hide?
I was able to fix the similar issue in checkout page by updating messages.js file.

But unable to locate the code from where to fix this.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately no!

Comment: Which version of Magento are you using? I have the same issue on a M2.4.3-p2 instance.

Answer (score -3):

Next time whenever the message come "The requested qty is not available" then right click on that and open inspect element, then using some local jquery code we will remove its css class, so that it should not disappear.  
This is a model file I found may be useful - /var/www/html/development_m241/m241/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Cart/AddProductsToCart.php

Comment: The message is on screen just for fraction of seconds, hardly user can read it. And I cannot locate mention file in Model folder. I am using Magento 2.4.

Comment: This file may be important - /var/www/html/development_m241/m241/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml   from your root follow this path - vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml  , you may need to override this file because direct changes are not recommended.

Comment: Once we got the div and class then we will use javascript setTimeout function to increase its display time.

Comment: Could you share some sample code on how to do that?

Comment: -1 for fast and bad response